# My regular expression does not work

Tags: php, regex

I just do not understand it, seems that regexes hate me.

I need to get from a HTML-Code a simple pattern

I need the word between   Tags.

For some reason, in a javascript online regex tool this works:

```
$pattern = '/<image>(.*?)<\/image>/';
```

An example I am searching through is this here:

```
<p>Die exakten Maße für die Gruppenmontage mit Bobilink sehen sie hier:</p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<p><image>classic_b montage link.jpg</image></p>
```

But I get just output of Array() My complete php code:

```
$zeilen = file('j25.sql'); 
$pattern = '/<image>(.*?)<\/image>/';
foreach ($zeilen as $zeile) {
    preg_match($pattern, $zeile, $matches);
}
echo '<h1>Matches</h1>';
print_r($matches);
```

Please help me somebody this is going to ruin the whole weekend if I am not getting it ready. Where is the mistake?

Thank you soo much

Comment: Question subject should be related

Comment: shouldn't `<image>` be `<img>`. Are you sure that the text you have provided is the one you are searching for a match. If you are getting the html out of a real web-page and searching for <image> in it, maybe that's the reason why the regex won't match.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the Regex, but have you tried checking if it's actually getting the contents of the file? Try using `file_get_contents()` instead of `file()` as it's probably not reading the contents, therefore has nothing to match.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! No the <image> is correct, it's an edited sql file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that `$matches` will only contain the match in the last line of the file, as its value is redefined with each iteration of the loop. You can either add the capture group match `matches[1]` from each line to another array, as in Romains answer, or use the following:

```
$zeilen = file_get_contents('j25.sql'); 
$pattern = '/<image>(.*?)<\/image>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $zeilen, $matches);

echo '<h1>Matches</h1>';
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the content between tags, it is stored in $matches[1].
In your code, $matches is erased at each line you analyse. To get an array of the results you should use an other variable :

```
$results = array();
foreach ($zeilen as $zeile) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $zeile, $matches)) {
        $results[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

And in your expression, you could replace "*?" by "+" (means one ore more)

Comment: +1, though the regex advice is dodgy: if there was more than one image in a line `.+` would match from the opening `<image>` to the last closing `</image>`.

Comment: @MikeM if there were more than one image, `.+` and `.*?` would do the same thing. The correct regex would be something like `[^<]+`, used with `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the `?` behavior, thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the regex... this works:

```
<?php 
$zeile = "<p>Die exakten Maße für die Gruppenmontage mit Bobilink sehen sie hier:</p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<p><image>classic_b montage link.jpg</image></p>";

// $zeilen = file('j25.sql'); 
$pattern = '/<image>(.*?)<\/image>/';
// foreach ($zeilen as $zeile) {
    preg_match($pattern, $zeile, $matches);
// }
echo '<h1>Matches</h1>';
print_r($matches); 

 ?>
```

To produce this output...

```
<h1>Matches</h1>Array
(
    [0] => <image>classic_b montage link.jpg</image>
    [1] => classic_b montage link.jpg
)
```

Comment: I expect there is something wrong with the file you are reading... looks like it has an sql extension, but you are matching against html content - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You test code works for me in a test php file...

```
$testStr = '<p>Die exakten Maße für die Gruppenmontage mit Bobilink sehen sie hier:</p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<p><image>classic_b montage link.jpg</image></p>';
$pattern = '/<image>(.*?)<\/image>/';
preg_match($pattern, $testStr, $matches);
print_r($matches); 

//outputs:   Array ( [0] => classic_b montage link.jpg [1] => classic_b montage link.jpg )
```

Can you post the contents of your data file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file has the correct server permissions so that PHP can read the contents.